# Comparing if two lists have the same elements based on a property

Tags: java

Suppose I have two lists:

```
List<EmployeeSummary> listA
List<Employee> listB
```

And I want to check if all employees in listA are represented in listB based on a common property “code” which is used in both EmployeeSummary.class and Employee.class. Both lists should have the same size and same employees based on its code.

If not I would like to throw an exception. I was thinking in something like:

```
if(!listA.stream().allMatch(listB::getCode)){
    throw new DummyException()
}
```

How can I represent the second list and the property to be compared?

(PS: the "listB::getCode" represented above doesn't work that way) :)

I would like to avoid having an inner stream.

Comment: 1) Sort both collections by your property value 2) compare each i element of first collection with i element of second.

Comment: java is really not the best language for this. would you consider using Kotlin do deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `listA`'s all element exists in `listB`

```
boolean isSame = listA.stream()
                      .allMatch(a -> listB.stream()
                                          .anyMatch(b -> b.getCode().equals(a.getCode())));
```

You can create a set of `code` from a list and check contains in O(1)

```
Set<String> set = listB.stream().map(e -> e.getCode()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then you can find in set for every list element

```
boolean isSame = listA.stream().allMatch(a -> set.contains(a.getCode()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I was trying to avoid using that inner stream (if that is possible in this case).

Comment: @lo_ol possible if both lists mantain a order or you create a set of code from a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by pairing the elements of both lists together. Kotlin does it much more easily, but in java something like this should work:

```
IntStream.range(0, Math.min(listA.size(), listB.size()))
        .mapToObj(i -> new Map.SimpleEntry<>(listA.get(i), listB.get(i)))
        .allMatch(entry -> entry.getKey().getCode().equals(entry.getValue().getCode());
```